# How To Set MonoDevelop Default C# Compiler Version

Tags: monodevelop, default

I am using MonoDevelop 5.9.6 on Ubuntu linux. I want to use C# 6 features and I have found the setting in the project options that allows me to change the compiler version to C# 6 for a single project. Its current setting is "default" and with that version 6 features don't work. I have looked through all of the menus / options / prefs / etc and I cannot find where to set the default compiler version.

Is it possible to change / set the default compiler version to C# 6 in MonoDevelop?

Thanks